How to handle React Native Authentication with Context API, AXIOS and Refresh Token
I try to implement React Native Authentication logic with JWT Refresh Token.
Here is what i've tried so far.
ReactContext with Provider:
const loadTokensFromStore = async () => {
    const accessToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(StorageKeys.ACCESS_TOKEN);
    const refreshToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(
        StorageKeys.REFRESH_TOKEN,
    );
    return { accessToken, refreshToken };
};

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
    const [authState, setAuthState] = useState<AuthState>({
        accessToken: null,
        refreshToken: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const getSession = async () => {
            const { accessToken, refreshToken } = await loadTokensFromStore();

            if (accessToken)
                setAuthState((prev) => ({
                    ...prev,
                    accessToken,
                    isAuthenticated: true,
                }));
            if (refreshToken)
                setAuthState((prev) => ({
                    ...prev,
                    refreshToken,
                    isAuthenticated: true,
                }));
        };

        getSession();
    }, []);

    const onLogin = async (userCredentials: UserCredentials) => {
        const { access_token, refresh_token } = await authEndpoints.loginUser(
            userCredentials,
        );
        setAuthState({
            accessToken: access_token,
            refreshToken: refresh_token,
            isAuthenticated: true,
        });

        await SecureStore.setItemAsync(StorageKeys.ACCESS_TOKEN, access_token);
        await SecureStore.setItemAsync(StorageKeys.REFRESH_TOKEN, refresh_token);
    };

    const onLogout = async () => {
        await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(StorageKeys.ACCESS_TOKEN);
        setAuthState({
            accessToken: null,
            refreshToken: null,
            isAuthenticated: false,
        });
    };

    const onRegister = async (userCredentials: UserCredentials) => {
        const { access_token, refresh_token } = await authEndpoints.registerUser(
            userCredentials,
        );
        setAuthState({
            accessToken: access_token,
            refreshToken: refresh_token,
            isAuthenticated: true,
        });

        await SecureStore.setItemAsync(StorageKeys.ACCESS_TOKEN, access_token);
        await SecureStore.setItemAsync(StorageKeys.REFRESH_TOKEN, refresh_token);
    };

    const value: AuthContextType = {
        onLogin,
        onRegister,
        onLogout,
        authState,
    };

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

App and Screens

export default function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
            <AppProviders>
                <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <Screens />
                </GestureHandlerRootView>
            </AppProviders>
        </>
    );
}



export const Screens = () => {
    const { authState } = useAuth();
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            {authState?.isAuthenticated && <NavigationBottomTabs />}
            {!authState?.isAuthenticated && <NavigationForUnauthorizedUser />}
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};


And my main problem is how to handle redirection to login page if user is not authenticated and how to handle refresh token logic with axios interceptors. I was searching solution in web but i couldn't find anything helpful.
My api endpoints:
export type Tokens = {
    access_token: string;
    refresh_token: string;
};

export type LoginUserPayload = {
    email: string;
    password: string;
};

export type LoginResponse = {
    access_token: string;
    refresh_token: string;
    user: {
        email: string;
    };
};

export type RegisterUserPayload = {
    email: string;
    password: string;
};

export type RegisterResponse = {
    access_token: string;
    refresh_token: string;
    user: {
        email: string;
    };
};

const loginUser = async (payload: LoginUserPayload) => {
    const response: LoginResponse = await api.post(`${API_URL}/auth/login`, {
        email: payload.email,
        password: payload.password,
    });

    return response;
};

const registerUser = async (payload: RegisterUserPayload) => {
    const response: RegisterResponse = await api.post(
        `${API_URL}/auth/register`,
        {
            email: payload.email,
            password: payload.password,
        },
    );

    return response;
};

const getSession = async () => {
    const response: Tokens = await api.get(`${API_URL}/auth/session`);
    console.log(response);
    return response;
};

export const authEndpoints = {
    loginUser,
    registerUser,
    getSession,
};


And axios with interceptors usage:

const redirectUnauthorizedUser = async () => {
    await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(StorageKeys.ACCESS_TOKEN);
    await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(StorageKeys.REFRESH_TOKEN);
};

export const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: API_URL,
    withCredentials: true,
});

api.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
    const accessToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(StorageKeys.ACCESS_TOKEN);
    const refreshToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(
        StorageKeys.REFRESH_TOKEN,
    );

    if (accessToken) config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
    if (refreshToken) config.headers.set("refresh_token", refreshToken);

    return config;
});

api.interceptors.response.use(
    (res) => res,
    refreshInterceptor(api, refreshToken, redirectUnauthorizedUser),
);

api.interceptors.response.use((response) => response.data);




type RefreshLogicFn = () => Promise<unknown>;

type RedirectUnauthorizedUser = VoidFunction;

const authErrorStatusCodes = [401, 403];

export const isAuthError = (error: unknown) => {
    if (isAxiosError(error) && error?.response?.status) {
        const status = error?.response?.status;
        return !!(status && authErrorStatusCodes.includes(status));
    }

    return false;
};

export const refreshInterceptor =
    (
        api: AxiosInstance,
        refreshTokenLogic: RefreshLogicFn,
        redirectUnauthorizedUser: RedirectUnauthorizedUser,
    ) =>
    async (error: unknown) => {
        if (!isAxiosError(error)) return;
        const originalRequest = error.config;

        if (isAuthError(error) && originalRequest && !originalRequest._retry) {
            originalRequest._retry = true;
            try {
                const session = await refreshTokenLogic();
                originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${session.access_token}`;
            } catch (e: unknown) {
                redirectUnauthorizedUser();
                return;
            }

            return api(originalRequest);
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
    };


export const refreshToken = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        authEndpoints
            .getSession()
            .then((response) => {
                resolve(response);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                reject();
            });
    });
};



Could you explain what i'm missing here?
